# Is it possible to assign a reserved public IP to a GKE deployment for egress traffic?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-vpc

I want *some* of my GKE deployments to use a public static IP for egress traffic to the internet.

Here is what I already know is possible:

- Use gcp's nat gateway and NAT ALL public traffic from a cluster/vpc
- Create a GCE instance with IP forwarding and create a routing rule to route specific traffic through the GCE instance- to selectively NAT traffic

I'd like to avoid either and just assign a reserved global IP to a GKE deployment/pod (like I can assign a reserved IP to an ingress). Is this at all possible?

I want outbound traffic from some pods (deployments) to use the same static public IP, but for most deployments I don't want to NAT their traffic at all.

I also can't use the underlying node's public IPs because I autoscale and the node's IP could change - you can't use reserved IPs for nodes as far as I know.

EDIT: Azure seems to support what I'm looking for with `azure-egress` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/egress. So I can see at least one provider has an official solution for this. I am wondering if GKE has something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should go with the 2nd option - Create a GCE instance that will serve as a NAT instance.

Then, you can assign different [network tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags) for different node pools in your cluster, so only one of your node pools will route its public traffic to the NAT instance you created.
You then can use [Node Taints and Tolerations](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-taints#creating_a_node_pool_with_node_taints), to make sure only the deployments you want to route to that NAT instance will be allocated to the nodes in your special node pool.
For example, configure this taint: `traffic=nat:NoExecute` and add the following toleration to your deployment:

```
tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: traffic
    value: "nat"
```

Comment: kind of a bummer if this is the only way right now. I can see at least Azure seems to officially support what Im looking for with their `azure-egress` service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/egress#create-a-service-with-the-static-ip

Comment: I'm not familiar with Azure, but according the link you mentioned, the networking architecture differs a lot from GCP. Anyway, I don't think there are other ways to do it in GKE, at this moment at least.